# Laravel: Model attribute and whereBetween

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Am I missing something but this is not working? I have model attribute getEntryEndingAttribute as so

```
    public function getEntryEndingAttribute ()
{

    if($this->whereBetween('ending', [now(), now()->addDays(1)])) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

Results what i'm getting from debug is

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `entries` where `ending` >= '2021-03-27 23:08:25'
```

When i'm doing same from controller

```
$entries = Entry::whereBetween('ending', [now(), now()->addDays(1)])->orderBy('ending', 'ASC')->get();
```

Results from debug is correct

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `entries` where `ending` between '2021-03-27 23:10:52' and '2021-03-28 23:10:52'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in object and getter contexts, so you don't have to use `whereBetween`.

Also, the function name is not correct and it should be `getEndingAttribute`. Moreover, you may look for something like:

```php
public function getEntryEndingAttribute()
{
    return $this->ending >= now() && $this->ending <= now()->addDays(1);
}
```

Comment: getEndingAttribute would replace the ending property, which may not what OP wants

Answer (score 1):

`getEntryEndingAttribute` returns a value to the model, it does not filter the entry when fetching.

`whereBetween` filters the entry when selected from the database.

For filtering you need a scope:

```php
public function scopeEntryEnding($query)
{
    return $query->whereBetween('ending', [now(), now()->addDays(1)]);
}
```

and use it as follows:

```php
$entries = Entry::entryEnding()->orderBy('ending', 'ASC')->get();
```